# A universal way of changing the PIN code on a mobile SIM card

Tags: sim-card, dual-sim, sim-pin

Is there a universal way to change the PIN code on a SIM card for a mobile/cell phone?

Will it work on both my phone's two SIM cards, SIM1 and SIM2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a universal way to change the pin code on a SIM-card for a mobile/cell phone?

Enter `* * 04 * oldPIN * newPIN * newPIN #` in the usual way that you dial a phone number (i.e. through the "Phone" app if it's on Android). This is defined by [ETSI GSM 02.30](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/02/0230/05.03.00_60/gsmts_0230v050300p.pdf#page=21).

> Will it work on both my phone's two SIM-cards, SIM1 and SIM2?

Dual-SIM phones were outside the scope of the standard, so it depends on the way each manufacturer implements its SIM selection UI.